# Decode input data on transaction

Tags: web3js

I have an ABI and the `input` value of the transaction and want to know what function has been called on a contract and with what arguments (one or multiple of different types), preferably using `geth`, `JSON-RPC` and some pseudo code that I can then translate into Ruby.

There are a couple of similar questions on SO but none of them really answered the question in a way that's understandable to someone new to Ethereum.

As an example, I use the `MetaCoin` [contract generated by Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts). I call the method `getBalance('0xfd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472')` and get the input `0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000fd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472`.

```
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getTransaction('0x5d7a91c9f068d723ac52480c0ef61b9bf3f7b52dc726046e0b47f1beaa2f44ff')
{ hash: '0x5d7a91c9f068d723ac52480c0ef61b9bf3f7b52dc726046e0b47f1beaa2f44ff',
  nonce: 5,
  blockHash: '0xd150b520eb69a621a7218722c0de5b270c9abc499a90a81ca96340e274599c28',
  blockNumber: 6,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  from: '0xfd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472',
  to: '0x8dec2f9cccbe718c7c51e9154f223eb226bb7942',
  value: { [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] },
  gas: 4712388,
  gasPrice: { [String: '100000000000'] s: 1, e: 11, c: [ 100000000000 ] },
  input: '0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000fd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472' }
```

The ABI is as follows:

```
[
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "addr",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "name": "getBalanceInEth",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "receiver",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "name": "amount",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "sendCoin",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "sufficient",
          "type": "bool"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "addr",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "name": "getBalance",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "name": "_from",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "name": "_to",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "name": "_value",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Transfer",
      "type": "event"
    }
  ]
```

How can I decode any input to know what method was called and what arguments were passed in?

**Update**

I've added all data of the block with the input field at the very bottom in the logs.

```
{"number"=>"0x09",
 "hash"=>"0xf543eba0c80d49beea1f934c0f0ad9f0babe272a8318312545d43e6b612e4006",
 "parentHash"=>
  "0xde7a61e8dd84b5e080da8e16430951f7f138347c77ed263d0093e367c9d30775",
 "nonce"=>"0x0",
 "sha3Uncles"=>
  "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
 "logsBloom"=>
  "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "transactionsRoot"=>
  "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
 "stateRoot"=>
  "0x269cfa04ca1fe73202f788397ece62c520c64d5da7225ba2af2d673a2e9892f2",
 "receiptRoot"=>
  "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
 "miner"=>"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "difficulty"=>"0x0",
 "totalDifficulty"=>"0x0",
 "extraData"=>"0x0",
 "size"=>"0x03e8",
 "gasLimit"=>"0x47e7c4",
 "gasUsed"=>"0x5a3e",
 "timestamp"=>"0x58c83fda",
 "transactions"=>
  [{"hash"=>
     "0xce1eaf03dd1dfa5898243711ebcc1dc5c6357701f5a6c19f0b1f84130cb651fa",
    "nonce"=>"0x08",
    "blockHash"=>
     "0xf543eba0c80d49beea1f934c0f0ad9f0babe272a8318312545d43e6b612e4006",
    "blockNumber"=>"0x09",
    "transactionIndex"=>"0x0",
    "from"=>"0xfd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472",
    "to"=>"0x8dec2f9cccbe718c7c51e9154f223eb226bb7942",
    "value"=>"0x0",
    "gas"=>"0x47e7c4",
    "gasPrice"=>"0x174876e800",
    "input"=>
     "0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000fd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472"}],
 "uncles"=>[]}
```

Comment: When you say "input" do you mean output? Because your example seems to indicate you want to parse output.

Comment: @SamuelHawksby-Robinson I've added more details to the bottom of the question to clarify.

Comment: If you want to decode data via a UI you could use a tool like the following which allows you to enter in a custom ABI or even easier would be to rely on its own massive internal ABI archive.

https://tools.deth.net/calldata-decoder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can refer to a packaged developed by Consensys
https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder

Comment: Awesome. This works very well and returns the name of the method (`getBalance`), the name of each argument passed in (`receiver`) and the value passed in (`0xfd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472`) for each argument. It doesn't return the type of the argument though?

Comment: Yeah. It does not return the type of arguments

Comment: I opened an issue, one friendly maintainer of the repo already added it

Comment: Cool. Quick work

Answer (score 4):

Ah ok, I understand what you are asking. You can do this `web3.toAscii(transactionID.input)` to get a human readable format.

See `web3.toAscii` https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii

So with your code it would be:

```
transaction = web3.eth.getTransaction('0x5d7a91c9f068d723ac52480c0ef61b9bf3f7b52dc726046e0b47f1beaa2f44ff')
input = web3.toAscii(transaction.input)
console.log(input)
```

Comment: This gives me `'ø²ËO\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ýF÷IùÙ\u0016\u0012/éX×øÕ­\u0003;\u0018tr'`. I'm not familiar with Ascii and I don't know how I could derive from this string that the method `getBalance(address)` was called with the argument `0xfd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472`.

Comment: @Samuel Hawksby-Robinson I used your command for my Tx hash (0x37361fd8eb5f78c7558ccfaa338c1935ecbc3d486f7a63c5b3e1b245779bc90e) However i receive these errors : "TypeError: web3.toAscii is not a function"  and also "ReferenceError: input is not defined" Thanks

Comment: @Questioner use web3.hexToAscii for later version of web3js

Comment: @migu because this answer is wrong, you can't decode tx data without knowing abi, since first 4 bytes of data is function selector and rest decodes according to abi arg types and sizes.

Answer (score 4):

You can now use the [`web3.eth.abi.decodeLog`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-abi.html#decodelog) function (web3 1.0).

Example from the documentation:

```
web3.eth.abi.decodeLog([{
    type: 'string',
    name: 'myString'
},{
    type: 'uint256',
    name: 'myNumber',
    indexed: true
},{
    type: 'uint8',
    name: 'mySmallNumber',
    indexed: true
}],
'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000748656c6c6f252100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
['0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f310', '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010']);
> Result {
    '0': 'Hello%!',
    '1': '62224',
    '2': '16',
    myString: 'Hello%!',
    myNumber: '62224',
    mySmallNumber: '16'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tool [ethereum-input-data-decoder](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-input-data-decoder) for decoding transaction input data given the ABI.

Example:

```
const InputDataDecoder = require('ethereum-input-data-decoder');
const decoder = new InputDataDecoder(`${__dirname}/abi.json`);

const data = `0x67043cae0000000000000000000000005a9dac9315fdd1c3d13ef8af7fdfeb522db08f020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000058a20230000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040293400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0f3df64775a2dfb6bc9e09dced96d0816ff5055bf95da13ce5b6c3f53b97071c800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000034254430000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`;

const result = decoder.decodeData(data);

console.log(result);

{
  "name": "registerOffChainDonation",
  "types": [
    "address",
    "uint256",
    "uint256",
    "string",
    "bytes32"
    ],
    "inputs": [
      <BN: 5a9dac9315fdd1c3d13ef8af7fdfeb522db08f02>,
      <BN: 58a20230>,
      <BN: 402934>,
      "BTC",
      <Buffer f3 df ... 71 c8>
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a simple ruby gem for decoding and encoding transactions input data in EVM based blockchains: https://github.com/rkotov93/evm-tx-input-decoder

Here's usage example regarding your case:

```ruby
# abi = parsed JSON ABI you provided
input = '0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000fd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472'
EvmTxInput::Decoder.new(abi).decode_input(input)

# Result:
# 
# #<EvmTxInput::Function:0x000000010b29a638
#  @arguments=[#<EvmTxInput::Argument:0x000000010b29ba88 @name="addr", @type="address", @value="0xfd46f749f9d916122fe958d7f8d5ad033b187472">],
#  @id="f8b2cb4f",
#  @name="getBalance">
```

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Nice way to start!

Answer (score 0):

On new web3.js 1.0 you must use: `web3.utils.toAscii(transaction.input)`.

Some times you should do a ``` let input = transaction.input.replace(/^0x/, ``); ``` to remove these useless characters from string start.

See [docs](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html?highlight=toAscii).