# How does one read whats going on in the Input Data of a Ethereum Transaction?

Tags: blockchain

Function: execute(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) ***

MethodID: 0xb61d27f6
    [0]:0000000000000000000000001dba1131000664b884a1ba238464159892252d3a
    [1]:00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000028b78bf6bd677fe7c17
    [2]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060
    [3]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    [4]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

**I am looking at the following data above, i understand that line 0 somehow translates into the reveicing address, can someone show me how the translation is done?
The second value is the amount to send i believe, can someone explain how this one translates into the correct amount?**

**Ive been trying to translate it from hex, but im clearly not understanding it.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode input data on transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13070/decode-input-data-on-transaction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) to decode the transaction parameters

```
const abi = require('ethereumjs-abi');

const data = Buffer.from([
    '0000000000000000000000001dba1131000664b884a1ba238464159892252d3a',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000028b78bf6bd677fe7c17',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'].join(''), 'hex');

const decoded = abi.rawDecode(['address', 'uint256', 'bytes'], data);

console.log(`Decoded: ${JSON.stringify(decoded, null, '  ')}`);
```

The output is

```
Decoded: [
  "1dba1131000664b884a1ba238464159892252d3a",
  "28b78bf6bd677fe7c17",
  {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": []
  }
]
```

Which means

- _to: 0x1dba1131000664b884a1ba238464159892252d3a
- _value: 0x28b78bf6bd677fe7c17
- _data: []  (empty array)

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking at is the transactionObject. You can see how the transactionObject is being used in the following example with `web3.js`:

```
transactionObject = {
  from: sender,
  to: receiver,
  value: amount
}
```

**source:** https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

But there are more than just 3 potential variables, as you can see in the link above.

Comment: This is contract [ABI data](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI) - it's completely different from the web3.js transaction object.