# Decode raw transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, raw-transaction, golang

How can I decode a raw transaction using Go / go-ethereum ? There is no method/function to read the raw bytes or the hex into a transaction https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types . Basically I just want to extract the destination address and the amount sent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I easily parse a raw transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/how-can-i-easily-parse-a-raw-transaction)

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/how-can-i-easily-parse-a-raw-transaction. If you think it is not a duplicate or are for some reason not satisfied with the answers to that question, please edit question explaining why it should be reopened.

Comment: @AjoyBhatia This question seems to specifically be about how to do this using go-ethereum.

Comment: @smarx - That is correct. I retracted my Close vote

Answer (score 4):

Using the official go-ethereum package:

```golang
import (
    "encoding/hex"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rlp"
)

func GetToAddressFromRawTransaction(rawTxHex string) (*common.Address, error) {
    rawTxData, err := hex.DecodeString(rawTxHex[2:]) // Remove hex prefix "0x..."
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var tx types.Transaction
    err = rlp.DecodeBytes(rawTxData, &tx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return tx.To(), nil
}
```

Look at the methods of the [`Transaction`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum@v1.10.16/core/types#Transaction) type to access data in the tx object.

Here's [a working code on github](https://github.com/G-Tarik/MyTools/blob/master/Ethereum_Parse_RawTX.go)

Comment: may I ask what are you doing in that loop to decode the public key ??? What are the sig1 and sig2 and why do you need a public key at all?

Comment: @Nulik For normal using of blockchain you don't need a public key. But if you want to research or to know deeper about EC cryptography you might be eager to find a public key. In my code sig1 and sig2 is a signature of the message. It consists of R+S+V (learn more about elliptic curves). R and S are known. V can be 00 or 01, so we just check both options.

Answer (score 1):

With introduction of EIP-1559, `rlp.DecodeBytes(..)` no longer works and you'd have to use `tx.UnmarshalBinary(..)` instead. Here's an [example](https://github.com/xphoniex/offline-wallet-go/blob/master/deraw/builtin.go):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)

func deraw() {

    // eip-1559 tx: 0xc2163f50770bd4bfd3c13848b405a56a451ae2a39cfa5a236ea2738ce44aa9df
    rawTx := "02f8740181bf8459682f00851191460ee38252089497e542ec6b81dea28f212775ce8ac436ab77a7df880de0b6b3a764000080c080a02bc11202cee115fe22558ce2edb25c621266ce75f75e9b10da9a2ae72460ad4ea07d573eef31fdebf0f5f93eb7721924a082907419eb97a8dda0dd20a4a5b954a1"

    // legacy tx
    //rawTx := "f86d8202b28477359400825208944592d8f8d7b001e72cb26a73e4fa1806a51ac79d880de0b6b3a7640000802ca05924bde7ef10aa88db9c66dd4f5fb16b46dff2319b9968be983118b57bb50562a001b24b31010004f13d9a26b320845257a6cfc2bf819a3d55e3fc86263c5f0772"

    tx := &types.Transaction{}
    rawTxBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(rawTx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err:", err)
        return 1
    }

    err = tx.UnmarshalBinary(rawTxBytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err:", err)
        return 1
    }

    spew.Dump(tx)
}
```

Alternatively, you can extract what you want using [`rlpdump`](https://github.com/xphoniex/offline-wallet-go/blob/master/deraw/deraw.go).

Comment: This should be the top answer! huge thx, been bugging me for days

Answer (score 0):

Here is a package I found out about from [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13070/decode-input-data-on-transaction):

https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder

See the code block titled **Decode Tx data**. I think this should do what you want.

Comment: Can you understand the difference between javascript and Go ?

Comment: Ok. Ok. I should read questions more carefully. go-ethereum also has a Javascript API to communicate with the node using IPC or RPC. That is what I have always used because I programmed in Javascript. Perhaps, when you said **Go / go-ethereum**, you meant an application in Go (i.e. not Javascript) interacting with the go-ethereum client?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example of how to read transaction values (ie, from address, eth value, etc..) in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    blockNumber := big.NewInt(5671744)
    block, err := client.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), blockNumber)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, tx := range block.Transactions() {
        fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex())        // 0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
        fmt.Println(tx.Value().String())    // 10000000000000000
        fmt.Println(tx.Gas())               // 105000
        fmt.Println(tx.GasPrice().Uint64()) // 102000000000
        fmt.Println(tx.Nonce())             // 110644
        fmt.Println(tx.Data())              // []
        fmt.Println(tx.To().Hex())          // 0x55fE59D8Ad77035154dDd0AD0388D09Dd4047A8e

        if msg, err := tx.AsMessage(types.HomesteadSigner{}); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(msg.From().Hex()) // 0x0fD081e3Bb178dc45c0cb23202069ddA57064258
        }

        receipt, err := client.TransactionReceipt(context.Background(), tx.Hash())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(receipt.Status) // 1
    }
}
```

If you have the raw tx hex, here's how you can decode it into a tx type:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "log"

    "github.com/c3systems/vendor.bak/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rlp"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rawTx := "f86d8202b28477359400825208944592d8f8d7b001e72cb26a73e4fa1806a51ac79d880de0b6b3a7640000802ca05924bde7ef10aa88db9c66dd4f5fb16b46dff2319b9968be983118b57bb50562a001b24b31010004f13d9a26b320845257a6cfc2bf819a3d55e3fc86263c5f0772"

    var tx *types.Transaction

    rawTxBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(rawTx)
    rlp.DecodeBytes(rawTxBytes, &tx)

    spew.Dump(tx)
}
```