# Get smart contract info from transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, golang

Lets take for example [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf85737c63387aae0e9fc016ff445417e5b12c32d6bd89c35fac15a72eaa97c6e), we can see that it did not transfer any ether, it interacts with a contract (that's why there's the stamp of the contract creation/execution).

Is there a way to get in go-ethereum these specific values?

Basically, how to get what was in a transaction if it was not about ether (eg uniswap).

Answer (score 1):

You can get more info about the transaction if you click on

1. "Click to see more"

You'll find that the input data box contains hints on what the call was about

```
Function: approve(address _spender, uint256 _amount)

MethodID: 0x095ea7b3
```

2. at the top on "Logs".
   You'll see that an `Approval` event was emitted and more details

```
Approval (index_topic_1 address _owner, index_topic_2 address _spender, uint256 _value)
```

The same info are available in the, respectively, (decoded) input/data and logs part of a `getTransaction` call to geth (or other clients).

You can find more info on decoding input data and logs [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13070/decode-input-data-on-transaction)