# How to get method name from transaction history (since the beginning and news in realtime)

Tags: etherscan, nodejs, infura, ethers.js

My job is to get all the method names from the token contract transactions from the beginning and to display the new transactions in realtime.

**1) Get all events**

For the moment I can display the `Transfer` events in realtime with:

```
const targetContract = new ethers.Contract(
    "0x30062EaBec018aC86430134E2c4Ff27e963Eda13",
    [
        "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount)",
    ],
    ACCOUNT
); 
targetContract.on("Transfer", (from, to, amount, event) => {
    console.log(event); 
});
```

Otherwise when I try to recover the logs with INFURA:

```
INFURA.getLogs("0x30062EaBec018aC86430134E2c4Ff27e963Eda13").then((data) => {     console.log(data); });
```

I don't understand what it shows me... It shows me a lot of information while there are not many events...

So for now I need to get all the events in realtime (and not just `Transfer`) and to be able to get all the old ones. Like `Add Liquidity`, `Max Tx` and other custom events

**2) Get method name**

I'm trying to decode method name from a TX.data but as I can see, with ethers.js or Infura it's not possible (or I missed something)

```
console.log(ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(     
[ "address user", "address rootToken", "bytes depositData"  ],     
ethers.utils.hexDataSlice(data, 4) ));
```

I tried this but I need to provide the corrects arguments...

So well... if I can't decode without arguments my other choice it's to know if it's possible to just get the method name.

Then I searched a transaction in a shitty coin and I found this:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9056f12256f1194d84d5f192087d20cd7fa8284b537e0476096eda08fde3394d

But when I'm using etherscan.io/api I don't have anything about the data (and not the method name)
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionReceipt&txhash=0x9056f12256f1194d84d5f192087d20cd7fa8284b537e0476096eda08fde3394d&apikey=

**In summary: I would just like to get the name of the methods and to be able to make a display like etherscan.io, like this:**

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: If you have the contract abi you can use an abi decoder https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13070/decode-input-data-on-transaction, if you don't have the abi perhaps you can use an external database like https://www.4byte.directory/.